# JiBX unmarshalling exception in spring ws

Tags: spring-ws, jibx

I am new to Spring WS and JiBX. I have not used annotations. I am getting the following error while using Jibx in Spring WS.

```
JiBX unmarshalling exception: No unmarshaller for element "{http://www.visu.com/pos/soapws/}orderRequest" (line 1, col 103); nested exception is org.jibx.runtime.JiBXException: No unmarshaller for element "{http://www.visu.com/pos/soapws/}orderRequest"
```

Here is my Endpoint and the spring configuration

```
public class OrderEndPoint extends AbstractMarshallingPayloadEndpoint{

private Marshaller marshaller;
private Unmarshaller unmarshaller;
private OrderService orderService;

public OrderEndPoint(final OrderService orderService, final Marshaller marshaller, final Unmarshaller unmarshaller) {
    super(marshaller);
    super.setUnmarshaller(unmarshaller);
    //this.marshaller = marshaller;
    //this.unmarshaller = unmarshaller;
    this.orderService = orderService;       
    System.out.println("This is Order End point constructor");
}

@Override
protected Object invokeInternal(final Object newOrder) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("This is test for Invoke Internal");
    final OrderRequest orderReq = (OrderRequest)newOrder;
    final Order order = orderReq.getOrder();
    this.orderService.placeOrder(order); 
    return "Order with the order number "+order.getOrderNumber()+" saved successfully";
}
```

}

```
<!-- Jibx marshellers -->
<bean id="unmarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jibx.JibxMarshaller">
    <property name="targetClass" value="com.visu.pos.soapws.model.OrderRequest"/>
    <property name="bindingName" value="binding"/>
</bean>

<bean id="marshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jibx.JibxMarshaller">
    <property name="targetClass" value="com.visu.pos.soapws.model.OrderResponse"/>
    <property name="bindingName" value="binding"/>
</bean>
```

Below is the Order.xsd which is used for binding

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://www.visu.com/pos/soapws/" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.visu.com/pos/soapws/">

  <xs:element type="tns:orderRequest" name="orderRequest"/>
  <xs:complexType name="orderRequest">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element type="tns:order" name="order" minOccurs="1"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:element type="tns:order" name="order"/>
  <xs:complexType name="order">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="customer" minOccurs="0">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="firstName" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="lastName" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="middleName" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
          </xs:sequence>
          <xs:attribute type="xs:long" use="required" name="customerNumber"/>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element type="tns:address" name="billTo" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="shipping" minOccurs="0">
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="STANDARD_MAIL"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="PRIORITY_MAIL"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="INTERNATIONAL_MAIL"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="DOMESTIC_EXPRESS"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="INTERNATIONAL_EXPRESS"/>
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element type="tns:address" name="shipTo" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="item" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="id" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="description" minOccurs="0"/>
          </xs:sequence>
          <xs:attribute type="xs:int" use="required" name="quantity"/>
          <xs:attribute type="xs:float" use="required" name="price"/>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute type="xs:long" use="required" name="orderNumber"/>
    <xs:attribute type="xs:date" name="orderDate"/>
    <xs:attribute type="xs:date" name="shipDate"/>
    <xs:attribute type="xs:float" name="total"/>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="address">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="street1" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="street2" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="city" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="state" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="postCode" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="country" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="orderResponse">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="orderResponse" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element type="tns:orderResponse" name="orderResponse"/>
</xs:schema>
```

Verified on the net that the Jibx implementation does not need Marshaller and Unmarshaller separately. Though I declared the marshaller it is throwing this error. I tried all options available but to no use. Please help in this regard. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

```
<bean id="orderEndPoint" class="OrderEndPoint">
    <property name="marshaller" ref="marshaller" />
    <property name="unmarshaller" ref="unmarshaller" />
    <property name="orderService" ref="orderService" /> 
</bean>
```

Please set the properties while creating the `OrderEndPoint` bean
construtor injection not needed.Just create setter and getter in `OrderEndPoint` for `orderService`.

**Note:** OrderRequest should be the marshaller. (you have configures as unmarshaller)